# Iviewer - artifcts in chrome after rotating image

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-plugins

I am using [iviewer](https://github.com/can3p/iviewer) for zooming images. There is a rotate feature to rotate the images in both directions.

In Google chrome, when you rotate the image in any direction, and thn try to zoom in and zoom out, some border type lines appear on the empty space in the container. Here is screenshot of the problme.[image]

You can open the [demo page](http://test.dpetroff.ru/jquery.iviewer/test/) of this plugin to see this behavior in chrome.

I tried using dev tool of chrome but the lines disappear as soon as I open the dev tool window. Is there any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got a [reply](https://github.com/can3p/iviewer/issues/33#issuecomment-9115536) from the [developer](https://github.com/can3p) of this plugin. Here are its contents.

> It seems very much like a browsers issue. I will report it to the
>   chromium bug tracker, but I don't think that there is something more
>   to do about it. Image artifacts appear when image has transform value
>   with angle set and is being resized.
>
> Here is [the link on the chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142341)

I hope it will be helpful for someone someday